# Can't sign into Pokemon Go with email/password

Tags: pokemon-go

So I tried signing in with my Pokemon account and it tells me I have the wrong email/password. Kinda right. I mean, I only remember signing up with gmail, and it has my old mail.com address. I keep entering the right password/passwords for both emails, but it keeps telling me I am wrong.

Comment: Did you click the google button on the start screen or did you sign up on pokemom.com?

Answer (score 0):

The PTC login (not the automatic Google one) has been just awful so far (the first week). They launched an update for iPhone that locked all PTC members out for about half a day. Beyond that their ability to connect has been far worse than Googles services. Likely because Googles auth servers are just more robust.

Either way, this is likely a temporary issue.